# How can I optimize switch-cases?

Tags: groovy

I've got a switch case like this:

```
def someString = 'hello1234bla'

// ...

switch (someString) {
    case {it.contains('1234')}:
        doSomething()
        break
    case {it.contains('2468')}:
        doSomethingElse()
        break
    default:
        throw new Exception("ERROR: Number not found")
        break
}
```

This seems to be quite a lot of code for something so seemingly simple. All I want is to have different functions be executed when *someString* contains a specific substring. Is there no simpler way to do this, apart from maybe an if-else cascade?

Comment: How about using a map, storing your functions and, upon entering a number cycle through each element in that map and call functions that match? I don't know if Groovy has such a data type but this concept is possible in Java etc.

Comment: @Krazor: In groovy its something like this `{1234: { doSomething()}}.each{ s, fn -> if (someThing.contains(s)) fn()}`

Comment: Yeiks, now that's not very readable to me. Non-the-less, doing it like that will give you the ability to quickly correlate and change user input and the corresponding function.

Comment: Well if you write it in five lines, it's more clear.  yet each is wrong and one should use a `for` here to short-circuit.

Comment: @cfrick Shouldn't .find() instead of .each() also work?

Comment: @user3216060 sure, works too

Comment: Simple in the terms of total lines of code, or easy to maintain? If the latter, I'd suggest using good ol' polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty close to what the comments above suggest, but I'll write out a working example with indentation etc and perhaps it will be a bit more readable:

```
def someString = "hello1234bla"

def found = [ 
  '1234': { println "do something" }, 
  '2468': { println "do something else" }
].find { pattern, action -> 
  if (someString.contains(pattern)) { action(); true }
  else false
} 

if (!found) throw new Exception("ERROR: Number not found")
```

this executes the first matching action and throws an exception if no matches were found. If you need to execute an action for every match, replace the [find](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)) call with a [findAll](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) call.

Another way of executing code based on a pattern in the string is the groovy String eachMatch method:

```
def someString = "hello1234blae"

someString.eachMatch(/1234/) { println "do something" }
someString.eachMatch(/2468/) { println "do something else" }
```

which uses regular expressions and runs the closure (the block in the curlies after the [eachMatch](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#eachMatch(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) call) once for every match. Thus:

```
someString.eachMatch(/e/) { println "runs twice" }
```

on the above string would execute twice as there are two 'e' characters in the string.